# How to acquire ERC20 tokens on a test net?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I want to interact with a smart contract on Rinkeby, but I need to have ERC20 tokens to do so. I know how to get Ether on Rinkeby, but how would I get ERC20 tokens? Do I have to deploy and ERC20 contract, and give myself some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner: Yes, only way to get ERC20 tokens in testnet is through deploying Test Token smart contract.

Comment: this makes satoshi sad